# jQuery getScript vs Embedding Script in File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getscript

I was wondering whether use jquery´s [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) or not.

I have a jQuery plugin that I need to include in my site, but I am unsure what to do and I am wondering if there is a difference between these approaches:

In my case, I have to include a rather big script, but only for IE browsers. At this moment I do it like this:

```
if($.browser.msie){
 //minifed code
}
```

Now I was wondering if this:

```
if($.browser.msie){
 $.getScript('link to minified script');
}
```

would have any advantages/disadvantages? Or if it is more or less the same thing?

Comment: I would take a look at YepNope.js for stuff like this

Comment: Isn't this mainly to be used if you want to roll a 3rd party script into a re-distributable plugin?

Comment: go for 2nd option .. read my explanation in answer

Comment: @AshirvadSingh It seems there are different opinions on what is faster, so I will try both versions and than mark an answer.

Comment: sure share with us too what you got outta it.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be disadvantages to getting an external script.

i.e. 
**ONE HTTP request**

```
if($.browser.msie){
 //minifed code
}
```

**TWO HTTP requests**

```
 if($.browser.msie){
 $.getScript('link to minified script');
}
```

Your browser can only generally cope with 2 http requests at any one time. So from a performance point of view, the first will be faster.

**further explanation**

with `getScript`, IE users will have a smaller request, (-the size of your "minified code"). But everyone else will have to download the external script everytime (+ the size of your external script * number of page requests) + delay in response due to extra HTTP request.

with the minified code everyone will have to download your size of your minifed code (+minified code size).

Presuming your minifed code is say 5K and is accessed 10 time that means:

*IE GetScript:*

**(5K * 10) + performance of using second HTTP request = 50K+**

*Non-IE*

**0**

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

*IE nonGetScript*

**5K**

*non-IE*

**5K**

Comment: Will the first also be faster for non-IE users?

Comment: It'll be the same one http request

Comment: it'll be the same one http request, but a shorter http response (sans the IE-only code).

Comment: Like @andrea says getscript won't cache your script either, which is bad!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :) I decided to **not** use `getScript` for now and in case i need to include more "plugins" in the future, I might consider [yenope](http://yepnopejs.com/) (as @Jason Sperske suggested before.)

Answer (score 3):

Is better to use:

```
if($.browser.msie){
 //minifed code
}
```

because `.getScript()` will never cache the file.

Comment: Is that true?  The source of jQuery appears to be injecting a script tag when you call getScript, if the browser would cache a handwritten script tag why wouldn't it cache an injected one?

Comment: yup: [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) cache is `false`.

Comment: the result is exactly the same but I prefere the file to be cached.

Comment: can this be overridden? If that script is big, you don't want non-IE users to load it (which they would if it is inlined).

Comment: It looks like overriding it would take direct use of the $.ajax() method (which lets you state if you want it to cache) or to globally override the jQuery cache setting $.ajaxSetup({cache: true });

Comment: ye, as Jason Sperske sad: `$.ajaxSetup({cache: true });`

Answer (score 1):

These are two completely different things.
In one case you have your script embedded to the page so it is accessible right away and you don't need any additional code to verify whether it is available or not.
However, in the second case you're loading the script as an external resource, which will mean that there can be situations when you will need to process possible errors of communication, script errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different between both the approaches.
The first approach where you are embedding will download the whole script even if the browser is not ie. It will increase the page size which overhead on performance of your page loads.

The second apporach would be better where you are loading script from external js file only when it is need that means only when the browser is IE. So the performance would be better in other browsers.

Also you mentioned that the script is very big. So it would be better to include that script in external js file. Since these files gets cached in clients machine adding to the performance. No need to fetch it again and again

Answer (score 0):

So according to the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L245) which you have to [drill down a bit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js#L29) you can see that getScript is adding a script tag for you, so there is no difference.  Other than the (small) bit of processing to start jQuery and process the JavaScript that adds the script element.  I think the big difference is it lets you programmaticly inject the script tag so you can add logic like a browser test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for embedding script in file, users which have another browser should not get it. `$.getScript` is just shorthand to `$.ajax` with `dataType` `script`, so it just loads script and execute it.